# How to resolve a dependency issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, rubygems

I am not entirely sure if this can even be done , but this is my error :

```
>> bundle install 

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    aws-ses (~> 0.4.1) depends on
      activesupport (>= 2.3.6)

    authlogic depends on
      activesupport (2.3.5)
```

I'm trying to get a Rails 2.3.5 app to have both these gems compatible with each other.

What can I do to make them work out?

Comment: I sometimes hack the code inside the gem themselves, editing the required versions but that's not risk-free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could try is upgrade your authlogic gem. I'm quite sure later versions of authlogic don't require activesupport to be version 2.3.5.

You do want to upgrade no further than version 2.1.6 at the moment, as it's the latest one that supports Rails 2.3.x

Of course your Rails app needs to be version 2.3.6 as well to get it working with this specific version of aws-ses, but that shouldn't be too big a problem.

Comment: Is there a way to look up a list of gem versions of a specific gem? Or even more specifically, is there a way to look up version of a gem that are compatible with other gems?